# HTML: Checkbox default value

Tags: html, cross-browser

When I submit a HTML form with a checked checkbox that doesn't have an explicitly defined `value`, Chrome sends `on` as a value for that field.

Is that the standard behavior? Or what can I expect from other browsers?

Comment: Yes it is standard! The checked value will be _on_ in every browser

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: Do you have a reference?

Comment: Checked for it but in vain. Couldn't find any. Just saying from self experience

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The HTML 4.01 specification does not specify the value of a checked checkbox. It just refers it saying that it is “on”, but this is just prose and does not say what the default value is. But it also says (under the [description of the `input` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4)) that the `value` attribute is required in this case.

So `<input type=checkbox name=foo>` has undefined behavior as regards to the value used, though in practice browsers use `value=on` as the default.

Comment: As per HTML 5, if the browser accesses the value via the DOM/IDL (or if the browser creates the DOM and gives access to the value, for example to javascript), the behavior is not undefined, but defined. The value is "`on`" then. This detail was unspecified in HMTL DOM in the past as the IDL didn't specify this case that detailed. In practice as you write this technically was always the case but remained undefined. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19094549/367456 - Valid HTML in the past normally required to write that attribute (e.g. HTML 2.0), since HTML 5 this is not necessary any longer.

Answer (score 10):

*HTML Living Standard* reflects this: The value is in mode "default/on",  that means it's value is "`on`" if no value attribute is provided. From [***4.10.7.1.16 Checkbox state (type=checkbox) - HTML
Living Standard (Sep 2013)***](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)):

> - The value IDL attribute is in mode [default/on](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value-default-on).
>
> [...]
>
> **default/on**
> On getting, if the element has a `value` attribute, it must return that attribute's value; otherwise, it must return the string "`on`". On setting, it must set the element's `value` attribute to the new value.

This is quite identically also part of another HTML specification, the ***W3C HTML 5 Aug 2013  Recommendation Specification*** has this as well:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value-default-on

---

*For reference my earlier comment:*

> Firefox (Sep 2013), Chrome (Sep 2013), Internet Explorer (6): "on". I suspect this goes back a long way. http://lxr.mozilla.org/classic/source/lib/layout/layform.c#86 - as most browsers need to have some default value for their own code objects I guess this "on" is just common.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers will send the value of a checkbox (in the POST data) only if it is checked. A check to see if a value (*any* value) for a particular checkbox is present in the POST data is all you need.

i.e.

```
// no need to check against 'on', 'true', '1' etc..
if(post data contains a value for checkbox1) {
    // checkbox 1 is checked
}
else {
    // not checked
}
```

Comment: mentioned because the actual value is immaterial and shouldn't be checked against ideally.

Comment: Even in 2012 Single page applications were a thing, making your comment invalid, we don't send actual form posts this way to the browser we want to get the value of the checkbox sometimes.