# HTML/Javascript Form Incorrect values being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Pretty straight forward issue.

I'm trying to create new list item entries when the user hits the "add" button.

When the user clicks the "add" button, the values being displayed from my form aren't correct.What currently gets displayed says "on".

I would like the list items to display the values of "age", "rel" and "smoker". Also, I need the list item values deleted when the user clicks "Remove Link".

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Side Note: I cannot edit any HTML. No JQuery. Only JS for this.

Thanks!

HTML

```
 <ol class="household"></ol>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label>Age
                <input type="text" name="age">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Relationship
                <select name="rel">
                    <option value="">---</option>
                    <option value="self">Self</option>
                    <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                    <option value="child">Child</option>
                    <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                    <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Smoker?
                <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="add">add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

JS

```
function validate(form) {
  fail = validateAge(form.age.value)
  fail += validateRel(form.rel.value)
  if (fail == "") return true
  else {
    alert(fail);
    return false
  }
}

function validateAge(field) {
  if (isNaN(field)) return "No age was entered. \n"
  else if (field < 1 || field > 200)
    return "Age must be greater than 0. \n"
  return ""
}

function validateRel(field) {
  if (field == "") return "Please select a relationship \n"
  return ""
}
document.querySelector("form").onsubmit = function() {
  return validate(this)
}
document.querySelector(".add").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  createinput()
};
count = 0;

function createinput() {
  field_area = document.querySelector('.household')
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var x = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  document.querySelector(".household").innerHTML = x;
  var y = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;
  document.querySelector(".household").innerHTML = y;
  var z = document.getElementsByName("smoker")[0].value;
  document.querySelector(".household").innerHTML = z;
  //var x = document.getElementsByName("age")()[0].value;
  //document.querySelector('.household').innerHTML = x;
  //var list = document.querySelector(".household")()[0].value;
  //list.getElementsByName("age")[0].innerHTML = "Milk";
  /*input.id = 'field' + count;
  input.name = 'field' + count;
  input.type = "text"; //Type of field - can be any valid input type like text,file,checkbox etc.*/
  li.appendChild(p);
  field_area.appendChild(li);
  //removal link
  var removalLink = document.createElement('a');
  removalLink.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
  }
  var removalText = document.createTextNode('Remove Field');
  removalLink.appendChild(removalText);
  li.appendChild(removalLink);
  count++
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not much clear, but I assume that you want to create new `li` entries on click of `add` button. The function `createinput()` can be modified as follows (using jQuery):

```
function createinput() {
  var age = $("[name=age]").val(),
      rel = $("[name=rel]").val(),
      smoker = $("[name=smoker]").prop("checked"),
      count = $(".household li").length;

  var elemt = "<li>" +
                "<p>Age: "+ age +"</p>" + 
                "<p>Relationship: "+ rel +"</p>" + 
                "<p>Smoker: "+ smoker +"</p>" + 
                "<p><a class='remove' href>Remove Field</a></p>" +
              "</li>";

  $(".household").append(elemt);
}
```

This will append the `li`s with the details in the form to the `ol` in the HTML.

Also, to remove the `li` on click of the `Remove Field` link, please add the following to your javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".household").on("li a.remove", "click" function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent("li").remove();
  });

});
```

**Edit 1**:

JavaScript Solution:

The problem was with your `createinput()`, which was overwriting the values of age, and rel with smoker. Correct that as follows:

```
function createinput() {
  field_area = document.querySelector('.household')
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var p1 = document.createElement("p");
  var p2 = document.createElement("p");
  var p3 = document.createElement("p");
  var x = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;
  var y = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;
  var z = document.getElementsByName("smoker")[0].value;
  p1.innerHTML = x;
  p2.innerHTML = y;
  p3.innerHTML = z;
  li.appendChild(p1);
  li.appendChild(p2);
  li.appendChild(p3);
  field_area.appendChild(li);
  //removal link
  var removalLink = document.createElement('a');
  removalLink.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
  }
  var removalText = document.createTextNode('Remove Field');
  removalLink.appendChild(removalText);
  li.appendChild(removalLink);
  count++
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the share, I can't use jQuery on this one actually. Only pure JS. :/

Comment: You mentioned `jquery` tag. So I thought it would be fine with you.

Comment: oh no worries so sorry

Comment: @spidey677 Please see my edit. That should solve the problem in plain JS.

Comment: Thanks my friend! That works beautiful! One question.. why does the "smoker" value says "on"?

Comment: @spidey677 [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12915174/2019247) will describe the reason. :)